# Firebug incorrectly reporting status of cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, firebug

An ASP.net 4.0 site I have is required to run under SSL all the time.  We have configured .Net to return SSL cookies like so:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

and

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

When I view the cookie information in Chrome it says the cookie is Secure.  When I view it in Firefox's Web Developer toolbar it says it is Secure.  Also have tried the FireFox plugin called "View Cookies" which again says Secure.

However if I view the cookies in Firebug by going to Firebug > Net > HTML > Cookies it says that none of the cookies are secure (the Security column is empty).  The very odd thing is that if I go to Firebug > Cookies it says the cookie IS Secure.

Am I misreading what the Net Tab in Firebug is telling me?  Should it not say the same thing as the Cookies tab?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Firebug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6368), which I fixed lately. The fix will be included in [Firebug 1.12a5](https://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.12).

Sebastian